# Is it acceptable to use digit and word form of numbers in the same sentence/paragraph?

Tags: sentence, numbers

To illustrate, this reads a bit awkward:

> In a country with 75 billion SMBs, at least seven billion of them should advertise.

What's the acceptable practice in such sentences ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The writing style I have come across most often is to write out in words numbers of ten or less (occasionally twelve or less) and use digits for all higher numbers.

In a sentence, using words gives a better flow, but obviously with higher numbers that flow would break down anyway, so I think your sentence works just fine as is.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out. I would have voted for you if I had the karma :|